# system program error detected

Tags: 16.04

How do I retrieve answers to, system program error detected, submissions? I get these messages often and I am requested to submit them to an on-line system. How do I retrieve any answers that may be generated from the on-line submissions I have submitted?

Comment: Generally, you don't need to. If your crash is due to a real bug (instead of a misconfiguration or other fault), a future package update may include the fix for the bug. From your perspective, the crashes will simply stop occurring one day.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have noticed about such errors.

Your system program error is given a default title (like "SEGFAULT in package XXX") and sent, together with data that may be relevant, to Launchpad (bugs.launchpad.net). There, your error is counted, and the count contributes to what is called the "hotness" of the bug. The hotter the bug, the more effort is put into resolving it, presumably.

Launchpad is a Canonical-owned website dedicated to tracking and resolving bugs. If you notice the title of the bug, you may even be able to find it there and see what is being done about it. On the Launchpad site you can even click an icon to show that this bug affects you, making the bug even hotter.